# Postgres: Aggregation sql with MAX and SUM returns two rows instead of one

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, max

We're building an aggregate by day for Call Detail Records (CDR's) from a Telco. The aggregate is on CREDIT_CHARGED and that's not a problem. However, we want to include in the same query the latest price plan that the subscriber was on. As subscribers change their price plan during a day, there are instances in the data where there are two different price plans during a day. Somehow there is also an instant in the data where I find two records with different price plan entries at the same time:

```
MID ACC SUB CALL_TIME   SUM_CREDIT
xx8567773   TSBS    0   2014-10-01 10:03:38 10499
xx8567773   TS  0   2014-10-01 10:03:38 1426
```

This breaks my aggregation SQL as it should return only one line for MID xx8567773 with 11925 as SUM_CREDIT

Here's the SQL that I was used:

```
select t2.mid, t2.acc, t2.sub, t2.call_time, t2.sum_credit
from 
(select t.mid, t.acc, t.sub, t.call_time,
    sum(t.credit) over(partition by t.mid, date(t.call_time), t.acc, t.sub) as sum_credit,
    max(call_time) over(partition by t.mid, t.acc, t.sub) as time_
from (
    select calling_isdn as mid, acc_profile as acc, subscriber_type as sub, call_sta_time as call_time, 
        credit_charged as credit
    from vms_cdricc
    where date(call_sta_time) = '2014-10-01'
        and credit_charged > 0
        and calling_isdn = 'xx8567773'
    ) as t
) as t2
where t2.call_time = t2.time_
```

How can the above SQL be changed to return only one row (I guess in this case it's impossible to say which record is younger or older, so it has to be random) when there are two records happening at the same time (who said data was always clean?).

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY returns a single row per group. It looks like you need to do something along the lines of

```
SELECT MID, CALL_TIME, sum(SUM_CREDIT)
...
GROUP BY MID, CALL_TIME
```

but I can't quickly tell how you might need to change the surrounding SQL to accommodate it. Including CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question always gives you better answers.